# Communication between native app & web app

Tags: android, web-applications

I want to make the communication between native app and web app in android.How to do it can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android services and broadcast intents allow two apps to communicate. For the web app, you'll need to bring some of the app native. I assume you're already using a WebView; you'll want to read the WebView documentation concerning how to tie JavaScript to native functions, and how native code can call into JavaScript that is in the page. (That JavaScript can either be a part of the page as provided by the server, or it can be injected into the page by your app.)